# HTML5 drag & drop placeholder sets parentNode to null onLeave (js vanilla)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

for my own website I'm trying to create an editor (based on contentEditables and HTML5 Drag and Drop features).

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bw320zo/1/
Be advised the code is messy, It's just a POC

---

### Problem:

The parentNode of the placeholder seems to be set to null every time I **hover** the **placeholder**.

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
>       at _detach
>       at HTMLDivElement._handleDragLeave

---

### Code explanation:

I create a simple div element on initialization:

```
placeholder = d.createElement('div');
placeholder.setAttribute('style', 'height: 25px; background-color: red;');
```

Each container has it's own events:

```
_on(elements, 'dragenter', _handleDragEnter);
_on(elements, 'dragover', _handleDragOver);
_on(elements, 'dragleave', _handleDragLeave);
_on(elements, 'drop', _handleDrop);
```

On hover I check for whether it has childrens if not I simply append the element, otherwise I add the element before or after (depending on location of mouse height):

```
function _handleDragOver(e) {
  var targetBoundingBox,
    targetMouseY;

  targetBoundingBox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  targetMouseY = e.pageY - targetBoundingBox.top;

  if (e.target.hasChildNodes()) {
    // TODO check Y axis (/2)
  } else {
    c.log('within');
    _within(e.target, placeholder);
  }
}
```

On element mouse leave I detach the placeholder (global var) from it's own parent:

```
function _handleDragLeave(e) {
  placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
}
```

It bugs the hell out of me. When checking the source on leave the placeholder element is still at the right place. Any ideas?

Fyi if you guys have a better idea on integrating a placeholder, do tell (no jquery or existing library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems here...

First, your `_handleDragOver` will always execute its else condition when hovering over the placeholder because it has no children.

```
function _handleDragOver(e) {
    var targetBoundingBox,
      targetMouseY;

    targetBoundingBox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    targetMouseY = e.pageY - targetBoundingBox.top;

    if (e.target.hasChildNodes()) {
      // TODO check Y axis (/2)
    } else {
      c.log('within');
      _within(e.target, placeholder); //<-- this guy
    }
  }
```

`dragOver` fires constantly while hovering over a valid drop target.

Next up, `_within` function:

```
  function _within(target, element) {
    target.appendChild(element);
  }
```

This little guy will cause you trouble if the placeholder hasn't already been removed by your `_detach` function. If you were to drop onto the placeholder, and it was not already removed, you would be trying to append it to itself... this will cause fireworks of the unfun type.

And now for `_detach`:

```
  function _detach(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
```

This gets called in your `_handleDragLeave` function. When you drop your drag, the `dragLeave` event is fired removing the placeholder.

Here is where the error comes in... Hovering over the placeholder causes it to be detached by dragLeave, but then it gets appended back by dragOver so on and so forth causing the flicker. The error you are getting is caused by a drop event trying to remove the placeholder, when it has already been removed by dragLeave yet hasn't been reappened by dragOver before it tries to remove it again because of the drop.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Anyways thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Goowik you're very welcome. Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some drag and drop stuff in the past. My problem then was that I did not catch that when working with drag and drop you need to use the DataTransfer object.

[DataTransfer Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

[JS fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/a9pt5zkh/2/)

**Step 1: Drag handler:**

```
function _handleDragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('myData', 'somedata');
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  //no e.preventDefault() here or it will not work.
}
```

**Step 2: Drag over handler:**

```
function _handleDragOver(e) {
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('myData');
  if(data && //is this valid drop data){
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

**Step 3: Drop handler:**

```
function _handleDrop(e) {
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('myData');
  if(data && //is this valid drop data){
    //do something with your dropped data.
    //re-render component inside editor-container
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

**Step 4: Drag end handler:**

```
function _handleDragEnd(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.clearData();
  //Check if drop was completed and do cleanup.
  //remove component from editor-item-list
}
```

`e.dataTransfer.dropEffect` is used to tell the drag and drop API that a drop action can be done. Without this the `drop` will never trigger. It is also used to change the icon of the cursor.

`e.dataTransfer.setData` do only take data as strings. This can be solved by converting it to JSON or you could handle the data transfer yourself inside the editor.

I find it to be simpler to work with data and not DOM-elements when doing drag and drop. Transfer the data and re-render it after the drop action.

**Update 1**

In chrome 59 `e.dataTransfer.getData` **does not work** inside of `drag over` and `drag end`. Maybe you are better of doing the data-transfer yourself. Remember you will still need to set the `dropEffect`.